# What would be a good name for the chat room?

Tags: discussion, chat

Taken from [The Real Essential Questions of Every Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223674/the-real-essential-questions-of-every-beta).

The Ethereum chat is called *Whisper*, a reference to the no longer existing `shh` communication protocol.

What would be a good name for the Substrate chat? *Gossip?*

Comment: This post is very inactive and so is the chatroom.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't even aware that Stack Exchange had "live" chatrooms in addition to the Q&A chat forum until I discovered this question and researched how to access it. I assume most other users don't know it exists either yet.

Should one of the chatrooms be called "Substrate Technical", as a direct replacement for the live chat that used to exist on Element?

The concern is whether it is possible to easily access and backup the chat history of chatrooms on Substrate Stack Exchange incase it gets shutdown.

Another concern with users accessing the chatroom during beta is that it may distract them from being as active in the Q&A chat forum during beta, which may be a more important metric to prevent the site being shutdown by Stack Exchange.

The first steps to access the list of chatrooms for the site Substrate Stack Exchange chatrooms was to click the 'chat' link (2) in the menu (1), which takes you to https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=sitehost=substrate.stackexchange.com.

[image: here]

There is currently only one chatroom named 'Substrate' the says its for general discussion. The next step to access the chatroom is to click the 'Substrate' link (3), which takes you to https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133964/substrate.

[image: here]

In the chatroom you may read the live feed, write a message (4), and send your message to the feed (5). I can't see how the feed is moderated. I can't see why posts that have been removed need to be shown and take up precious UI real estate.

[image: here]

It suggests the creation of more subject-specific rooms, and says a single room with every possible discussion (e.g. only our 'Substrate' general discussion room) isn't very helpful, so perhaps that should be renamed to 'Welcome'.

I think other rooms should be subject-specific, with core chatrooms named based on the most popular tags that are used in the Q&A chat forum.

If there was a chatroom named 'Gossip' then I think it should say it is for subject-specific discussion relating to Substrate's Gossip protocol with a link to its documentation [here](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sc_service/index.html?search=Gossip).

I also wasn't aware that Substrate Meta existed on Stack Exchange (where this question and my reply is being posted), or how I got here until now, and how to switch back to Substrate on Stack Exchange, which I have shown below:

[image: here]

Comment: i'll remove this post shortly as it was downvoted. i get the feeling nobody cares about the live chat anymore

Comment: Live chat is one of those things that depends the site culture.  Some sites have highly-active chat rooms, others don't.

Comment: Previously the site community here used a Live chat channel https://matrix.to/#/#substrate-technical:matrix.org, which still has 9856 users even though it is now deprecated and posts aren't allowed anymore. I used it almost everyday. It was around since about 2019 and was very active. A few months ago that community was directed to migrate to the site https://substrate.stackexchange.com, where there is an active Q&A forum, but the Live chat here is inactive, so I suggested some reasons why that might be the case.

Comment: The problem with chat is that it doesn't scale. People get lost and have to re-ask questions and it's not anywhere near as (self) organised as stack exchange's questions and answers. That said there are times when a chat would be more helpful especially if you're very unsure as to what question you should really be asking... I personally think we should have both.